pop_saveset problem when using EGGLAB preprocess the dataset
I want to preprocess the EEG data with EEGLAB, when I use the pop_saveset to save the process dataset, but it report an error about "pop_saveset error: argument 'filepath' must be a string"。 However, the class of filepath is string, how to save this problem?
base = "E:\\datasets\\Simultaneous_EEG_NIRS\\eeg";
EEG.filepath = strcat(base, subfolders(i).name, '\\');
fprintf(EEG.filepath)
EEG = pop_runica(EEG, 'icatype', 'runica', 'extended',1,'rndreset','yes','pca',28,'interrupt','on');
EEG = pop_saveset(EEG, 'filname', strcat(files(j).name(1:end-4), "_ICA.set"), 'filepath', EEG.filepath);

The printed information is
>> fprintf(class(EEG.filepath))
string>> 
>> fprintf(EEG.filepath)
E:\datasets\Simultaneous_EEG_NIRS\eegVP001\>>


solve the above question
